# Hit a Wall Webscraping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am very new at this. I'm using Eclipse SDK with PyQt4 (to unearth any stuff obscured by javascript). I am attempting to discover links to results from a site. For example: http://www.mrtzcmp3.net/billy_jean_Bs.html

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtWebKit
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Render(QtWebKit.QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        QtWebKit.QWebPage.__init__(self)
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

url = "http://www.mrtzcmp3.net/billy_jean_Bs.html"

r = Render(url)
content = unicode(r.frame.toHtml())

print content.encode('utf-8')
```

Edit: This retrieved page source is not revealing any of the download button links for the url above ... The extracted page source from the code above is here: http://pastebin.com/HyKnPUER

Comment: There are LOTS of hrefs in the snippet you posted; you'll need to be more specific about which one you're looking for.

Comment: Also, to post a snippet of code in StackOverflow, you need to indent it by four spaces. The simplest way is to use the `{}` button above the input box, which will indent it for you (where "it" is "whatever you have highlighted when you hit the button). Please don't post the entire HTML here, or the question will become unreadably long; just post the snippet containing the one link you're interested in.

Comment: To be more concise, any red download button on these results: http://www.mrtzcmp3.net/billy_jean_Bs.html ... is not discovered in the page source.

Comment: I tried to edit in some of the extracted page source but it was somehow getting processed even with the {}, but anyways my problem is I cannot discover and of those download button links

Comment: Get this href (without random letters) and try to open in browser. I tried one. I think this address is correct and server redirect me to new address with random letters. Your script have to follow redirection.

Comment: Sorry - my mistake - I get url from browser not directly from source. But it have to be some javascript which add random letter - you have to test all javascript code. Long work :)

Comment: ok I figure my javascript tool was like a nutcracker, apparently there is more to it than that

Comment: I found one thing. All my links ends with string "kTvde6rU" and the same string I found in cookies named "haras". Check your cookies.

Comment: Another thing. Add own 8 random letters (for example "aaaaaaaa") to the end of href and try to open it in browser.

Comment: Jeez I didn't even notice they were identical I was so focused on analyzing 1 link. THANK YOU

Comment: Sometimes I can open correct page using href without random letters and sometimes I can't open using href with random letters (in another browser without cookies). Maybe cookies are more important than random letters. Some servers check cookies, user-agent, and other thing to eliminate bots/scripts.

Comment: Yea I think there is some hard limit on that site for downloads, or there used to be and it is dormant. Not sure if I can solve this question or anything but thanks again.

Comment: Sometimes webscraping scripts have to behave like human :) Good luck.